# boot cd problem

Tags: boot, bootloader, backtrack

I installed ubuntu 13.10 on CD, in the boot turned on only reading from the disc, but at startup I get the message "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key". On hd i have backtrack 5, lilo and grub see only backtrack. What should I Do?

Comment: did you change the boot order in bios to cd drive as first option?

Comment: Yes. I change order : cd drive first, hd second

Comment: did you properly burn the iso image to cd?which software did you used for that?what was the size of your cd?

Comment: That image working fine on other computer

Comment: did the ubuntu iso image correctly fitted to the 700 mb cd?

Comment: Nope, Ubuntu iso has 896 MB. I record it on dvd.

Comment: did you burn it as a image file?

Comment: Nope. I burn it as a normal dvd ~all files from iso

Answer (score 0):

- Burn the iso as an image file so that it will be boot.
- See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) link to make a bootable ubuntu dvd.